# What algorithm can I use to generate a 48-bit hash for unique mac addresses?

Tags: linux, hash, mac-address

Is there any simple to use hashing algorithm to generate a 48-bit hash? I need to generate unique MAC addresses from unique input strings. There are no security issues here, just a question of mapping it to MAC address space (which is 48 bits).

I thought about CRC32, which is just 32 bits and easy (and `cksum` is on every Linux), and use them for the lower 32 bits, but the collisions are pretty high if it is more than a few hosts.

If I could get 48 bit hash, I could mask the second least significant bit of the 8 most significant bits to ensure it is a Locally Administered Address. The loss of a single bit is minor.

Conversely, I could use a longer hashing algorithm (MD5, SHA1, etc.) and just take the 48 most significant or least significant bits.

Is there a simple way to do this?

My preference is command-line utility, but if I have to write short python or similar, no big deal.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/299556/how-to-generate-a-random-mac-address-from-the-linux-command-line

Comment: @Terry excellent! Mind you, they are making it only 40 bits, and are just taking the most significant 40 bits. I am not sure the impact of that vs trimming it some other way. But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After 2 years, here's an idea, in a real application (very close to what you needed).

I just needed a serial number of only 48 bits for a custom board that doesn't have a non-volatile memory. The board features a STM32 processor that has an unique ID of 96 bits (STM32_UUID).

Here is the complete C code:

```cpp
#define STM32_UUID                      ((uint8_t*)0x1FFFF7E8)

// board SN 48 bit
static uint8_t BoardSerial[6]; 

void setBoardSerial(void)
{
  uint64_t hash = fastHash64(STM32_UUID, 12, 1234554321);
  memcpy(BoardSerial, &hash, 6);
}

static inline uint64_t mix(uint64_t h)
{
    h ^= h >> 23;
    h *= 0x2127599bf4325c37ULL;
    h ^= h >> 47;
    //
    return h;
}

uint64_t fastHash64(const void * buf, size_t len, uint64_t seed)
{
    const uint64_t m = 0x880355f21e6d1965ULL;
    const uint64_t * pos = (const uint64_t*)buf;
    const uint64_t * end = pos + (len / 8);
    const unsigned char * pos2;
    uint64_t h = seed ^ (len * m);
    uint64_t v;

    while(pos != end)
    {
        v  = *pos++;
        h ^= mix(v);
        h *= m;
    }

    pos2 = (const unsigned char*)pos;
    v = 0;

    switch(len & 7)
    {
        case 7: v ^= (uint64_t)pos2[6] << 48;
        case 6: v ^= (uint64_t)pos2[5] << 40;
        case 5: v ^= (uint64_t)pos2[4] << 32;
        case 4: v ^= (uint64_t)pos2[3] << 24;
        case 3: v ^= (uint64_t)pos2[2] << 16;
        case 2: v ^= (uint64_t)pos2[1] << 8;
        case 1: v ^= (uint64_t)pos2[0];
                h ^= mix(v);
                h *= m;
    }

    return mix(h);
}
```

I tested this solution on a batch of about 200 units (boards) and there was absolutely no problem, no conflicts. I've seen a lot of people having this issue, when they needed a smaller device ID that somehow originates from a large unique unit serial number.

Alternatively, you may search for an implementation of *Bobcat 48 bit hash*.